# Predicting continuous valued output

Tags: deep-learning, keras, one-hot-encoding

I am working on predicting Semantic Textual Similarity (SemEval 2017 Task-1) between a pair of texts. The similarity score (output) is a continuous value between [0,5]. The neural network model (link below), therefore, has 6 units in the final layer for prediction between values [0,5]. The objective function used is the Pearson correlation coefficient and softmax activation is used. Now, in order to train the model, how can I give the target output values to the model? Since there are 6 output classes, I should probably send one-hot-encoded vectors of the output. In that case, how can we convert the output (which might be a float value such as 2.33) to a one-hot vector of length 6? Or is there any other way of specifying the target output and training the model?

Paper: http://nlp.arizona.edu/SemEval-2017/pdf/SemEval016.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If the value you're trying to predict is continuously-defined, you might be better off configuring this as a regression architecture.  This will be simpler to train and interpret and will give you non-integer predictions (which you can then bucket or threshold however you please).

In order to do this, replace your softmax layer with a layer containing a single neuron with a linear activation function.  Then you can simply train this network using your real-valued similarity numbers at the output.  For loss function, you can use MSE / L2 unless you have a reason to do otherwise.